# Get User ID Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

```
function get_user_id() 
{
    global $cookie;
    $userid = NULL;

    if (isset($cookie->id_customer))
    {
        $userid = $cookie->id_customer;
    }

    return $userid;
}
```

Why the user ID keep return null even with login?

Comment: Where did you put this code, a module you created or a controller ?

Answer (score 9):

If using Prestashop 1.5 use `Context` object instead:

```
$this->context->customer->id;
```

or

```
Context::getContext()->customer->id
```

If there is no context inherited from parent classes.

Answer (score 0):

$params['cookie']->id_customer

and you shouldnt use global variables.